# Thymeleaf local @{} urls not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am using thymeleaf with springboot, all the links which I mention with a local url are not working. I even checked the network tab on the browser and all css and js resources load correctly but somehow have no effect.Here is some of the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head th:fragment="common-header">
<title>Fullstack app skeleton</title>
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css}"
      rel="stylesheet"></link>

<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link type="text/css" th:href="@{/css/styles.css}" rel="stylesheet"> 
</link>
</head>
<div th:fragment="before-body-scripts">
<script th:src="@{/webjars/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js}"></script> 
<script th:src="@{/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js}"> 
</script>
<script th:src="@{/js/fullstackapp.js}"></script>
</div>
</html>
```

Also, I have checked pom.xml and all dependencies have been loaded correctly. In above code in  when I mention the absolute url (https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css) then all the bootstrap features work, but when I use the reference to the local jar it doesn't. Can someone suggest a possible reason???

Comment: can you post your controller code for getting this template and your `pom.xml`?

Comment: Hey thanks for pointing it out, turns out somehow by mistake the url in request mapping got deleted..everything resolved now...my bad.

Answer (score 0):

I am using one `.java` file to mapping `Bootstrap` and `Jquery`

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/bootstrap/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/jquery/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/jquery/3.0.0/");
    }
}
```

Here is my `html` code:

```
<link th:href="@{/resources/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css}" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script th:src="@{/resources/jquery/jquery.min.js}"></script>
<script th:src="@{/resources/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js}"></script>
```

Hope to that help you